# Is the given function injective, surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> The following function is obviously injective, surjective and
>   bijective, but I'm not really sure how to prove this. N = {0,1,2,...}

$f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $f(x,y)=x+y$

Comment: Are you sure that "obvious" is the right word to use? It's not injective, nor is it surjective if $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, …\}$.

Comment: Specifying the codomain of the function would be important to determine if the function is truly surjective as well.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that $\mathbb{N}={0,1,2,3\cdots}$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer edited it.

Comment: Ok, so surjectivity is now ok (and you should be able to write a **very** specific $f(**, **) = n$ for any given $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But injectivity still isn't ok.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the function is clearly surjective, yes. Note that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you have $(0,n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ for which $f(0,n)=0+n=n$, as just one potential example.

However, injectivity fails for various pairings. Just as one specific example, $f(1,2)=f(0,3)=3$. However, $(1,2)\neq(0,3)$, thus not injective (and in turn, not bijective).

Comment: Thanks, everything clear now!